# In Solidity, can the constructor function have the same name as the contract?

Tags: function, constructor

According to this [article](https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2017/12/08/writing-a-very-simple-smart-contract/), the constructor - or initialization - function has the same name as the contract.  However, the remix compiler returns an error when I have a function with the same name, saying "defining constructors as functions with the same name as the contract is deprecated.  Use "constructor(...) { ... }" instead."

So, my question is, is using the same name in this situation something that should simply be avoided?  (Perhaps it is an out of date practice?)

Answer (score 7):

Since `Solidity v0.4.23`, constructors are now specified using the `constructor` keyword:

```
    constructor () {}
```

Just to compare with the old ways, say we have a Smart Contract called `Employee`, in the past, you'd specify the contract with its constructor like this:

```
    contract Employee {
      // constructor
      function Employee() public {
        // ...
      }
    }
```

But the acceptable way to specify the Employee Smart Contract now is:

```
    contract Employee {
      // constructor
      constructor() public {
        // ...
      }
    }
```

Using the name of a contract as its constructor is now deprecated.

Comment: Here's a related Ethernaut level: https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/level/0x5732B2F88cbd19B6f01E3a96e9f0D90B917281E5